# Copy A form to use in the same project

Tags: vb.net

I need to have 8 forms of the same format within the same project

I dont really want to specifically place all the buttons etc in each of them

Is there a way i could copy and paste the format and then change all the button names etc?

The program is a flight booking system so for different flights on the same plane type i need multiple forms

Comment: You are using visual Studio  ?

Comment: Yes i am @BeldiAnouar

Comment: why not just click and hold the mouse over the items that you want, and then paste them into your destination form? just make sure your form is the same size as all the rest

Comment: or if you are using WPF, just copy the xaml code and paste it on the new form.

Comment: Copy paste i Solution explorer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To duplicate a Windows Form, you have to do these simple steps :

1- Open the folder project in File Explorer.

2- Copy the three files, `.vb`, `.Designer.vb`, `.resx` of the form that you want to copy.

3- Rename the files with the name you want.

4- Open the file with a text editor for example `Notepad++`.

5- Modify the `Class` name in the `.vb` and `.Designer.vb` file.

6- Include those files in the project.

Below an example demo :

[image]

Comment: I'm glad To Hear that, Thank you Too.

Answer (score 4):

Ok you can do copy past from your form1 ,a form CopyOfForm1 shoud be created .

- you change name "form2" instead of "CopyOfForm1"
- Change name of class "form2" instead of "CopyOfForm1"
- In CopyOfForm13Desiner.vb you must also change name of class "form2" instead of "CopyOfForm1"

Have a look at this Gif picture :

[image]